# generalized Riemann Integrability of $f\cdot g$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, gauge-integral

Let $\mathcal{R}([a.b])$ the set of all Riemann-integrable functions in $[a,b]$.
Let $\mathcal{R}^{*}([a,b])$ the set of all Generalized Riemann-Integrable functions in $[a,b]$ (I'm talking about the Henstock-Kurzweil Integral).

We know that, if $f,g\in\mathcal{R}([a,b])$, so $f\cdot g\in\mathcal{R}^{*}([a,b])$. Can we say the same for Generalized Riemann- Integral?

Saying different, $f,g\in\mathcal{R}^{*}([a,b])\Rightarrow f\cdot g\in\mathcal{R}^{*}([a,b])$?

Comment: What is the generalized Riemann integral? I do not recall encountering that concept, at least by that name.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I think it's mentioned in Bartle's texts. I don't think I've seen the terminology elsewhere.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta After some searching, I think it's more commonly known as the [Henstock-Kurzweil integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral).

Comment: Can you edit that into the question? It would be much easier to answer if there was a description of the less standard concept or a link to it.

Comment: Sorry, I edited up. I'm talking about the Henztock Kurzweil Integral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not true.  For instance, let $f(x)=\frac{\sin (1/x)}{x}$ and let $g(x)=\operatorname{sgn}(f(x))$.  Then $f$ and $g$ are both Henstock-Kurzweil integrable on $[0,1]$, but $f(x)g(x)=|f(x)|$ is not.  The point is that the Henstock-Kurzweil integral allows for a kind of "conditional" (rather than absolute) convergence, which can turn into divergence when you multiply by a function that makes the product always have the same sign.

Comment: Old answer, but I will comment anyway since I added an answer.  In fact the function $f(x)=x^{-1}\sin x^{-1}$ has an improper Riemann integral on $[0,1]$.  The Henstock-Kurzweil integral includes all improper Riemann integrals.  So the example shows that the product of two functions, one improperly Riemann integrable and one Riemann integrable, need not be improperly Riemann integrable.  In particular it is an easy example for this question about a much larger integral.

Answer (score 0):

Another (recent, i.e., 2022) question pointed to this one.  So even at this late date I should point out these facts in case someone else is directed here and wants the definitive answer, not just an isolated counterexample to a naive question.

1. The product $f(x)k(x)$ is Lebesgue integrable on an interval $[a,b]$ for every integrable function $f(x)$ if and only if the function $k(x)$ is essentially bounded

[First proved in H. Lebesgue, Ann. Fac. Sci. Univ. Toulouse (3) 1, 25–117 (1910), in particular, pp. 38–39].

2. The product $f(x)k(x)$ is Denjoy-Perron integrable on an interval $[a,b]$ for every Denjoy-Perron integrable function $f(x)$ if and only if the function $k(x$) is   equivalent to a function of bounded variation.

[The "if" part is ancient history (I don't know the source).  The "only if" is in Sargent, W. L. C. *On the integrability of a product*. J. London Math. Soc. 23 (1948), 28–34.]

The question is stated for "the generalized Riemann integral" or "the Henstock-Kurzweil integral."  The Denjoy-Perron integral is equivalent to these and was first by about half a century.  Let's not forget that.